# pairwise comparison of binary matrix using vba

Tags: vba, matrix

I have a binary matrix like this, (but with over 200 rows and 100 columns).

```
 A  1     0     0     
 B  1     1     1     
 C  0     0     1
```

I have to do a pairwise comparison for each row with the following condition, if both cells have 1 then the results is 1, if both cells have  0 or 1 and 0 then the result is 0

which results in a new matrix like this,

```
AB= 1 0 0

BC= 0 0 1

AC= 0 0 0
```

Since I have a huge matrix, is there an easy way to do this in vba?

Comment: can be done by looping

Comment: i dont understand this logic. can you better explain

Comment: @mehow it's like a bitwise comparison

Comment: so you would only have 1 if both cells are 1s? what if they are both 0s? in mathematical logic 0 and 0 would be 1

Comment: If you compare n rows with eachother, you get n*(n-1)/2 result rows. Quite a lot for n = 200+  Or would it be sufficient to compare adjacent rows only?

Comment: i am not quite sure about the 0:0 as in mathematical logic that's a one. but in your sample the 0:0 is a zero so my answer suits your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have set up my spreadsheet *Sheet1* like this

[image]

with the below code

```
Option Explicit

Private nxt As Long

Sub Main()
    nxt = 1
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents
    For i = 1 To Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r1 = Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
        For j = i + 1 To Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set r2 = Sheet1.Range("A" & j)
            £ r1 & r2
            CompareRows r1, r2
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub CompareRows(i As Range, j As Range)
    Dim c As Long
    For c = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
        If (i.Offset(0, c) = 1) And (j.Offset(0, c) = 1) Then
            Sheet2.Cells(nxt, i.Offset(0, c).Column) = 1
        Else
            Sheet2.Cells(nxt, i.Offset(0, c).Column) = 0
        End If
    Next c
    nxt = nxt + 1
End Sub


Private Sub £(s)
    If Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Range("A1")) Then
        Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = s
    Else
        Sheet2.Range("A1") = s
    End If
End Sub
```

The code builds a matrix in *Sheet2* and it ends up like this

[image]

---

note you can add more rows and more columns and this will still work for you.

Comment: Nice! What is the meaning of "£ r1 & r2"?

Comment: @AxelKemper the `£` is just the name of the £ sub. the `£ r1 & r2` calls the sub passing one argument to it - concatenated r1 & r2 which become one String(Variant) which is the letter combinations. The `£` sub prints out all the possible combinations of rows into `Sheet2`

Comment: OK. "£" was not visible without scrolling down. I was not aware that such names are allowed.

Comment: well there are lots of tricks people aren't aware off :P I mainly use write a `£` sub as a wrapper for `debug.print`. Instead of typing `debug.print` I prefer just typing `£` with one argument or *paramArray*. The implementation of the `£` depends on the complexity of the problem/code